# Redirecting traffic through ssh tunnel

Tags: iptables, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I'm trying to redirect the traffic coming from clients to external proxy server.

I've the following architecture

```
                        +----------------------------+                       
                        |                            |                       
                        |        External Server     |                       
                        |                            |                       
                        +------------+---------------+                       
                                     |eth0 public ip                         
                                     |                                       
                                     |                                       
                                     |                                       
                                     |eth0 pubic ip                          
                        +------------+---------------+                       
                        |                            |                       
                        |      Localnet Gateway      |                       
                        |                            |                       
                        +------------+---------------+                       
                                     |eth0 192.168.1.1                       
                                     |                                       
                                     |                                       
                                     |                                       
                                     |                                       
                                     |                                       
+---------------------+              |                 +--------------------+
|                     |              | eth0 192.168.1.3|                    |
|   Client            +--------------+-----------------+   Clients gateway  |
|                     |eth0 192.168.1.2                |                    |
|                     |                                |                    |
+---------------------+                                +--------------------+
```

I ran [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/) on clients' gateway and it tunnels all traffic from `Clients gateway` server to the external server, but not the traffic coming from clients.
When dumping tcp connections on `Clients gateway` I can see the response and reply to the client but can't connect to the internet. These are iptables after running sshuttle:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [145:13378]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:sshuttle-12300 - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j sshuttle-12300
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.2/32 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.3
-A OUTPUT -j sshuttle-12300
-A sshuttle-12300 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -p tcp -j RETURN
-A sshuttle-12300 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12300
```

and the `tcpdump -nni eth0 host 192.168.1.2 and port 80` output:

```
21:10:22.812066 IP 85.12.58.8.80 > 192.168.1.2.64833: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
21:10:23.313912 IP 192.168.1.2.64833 > 85.12.58.8.80: Flags [S], seq 4176760380, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:10:23.313926 IP 85.12.58.8.80 > 192.168.1.2.64833: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
21:10:23.316556 IP 192.168.1.2.64834 > 212.73.221.202.80: Flags [S], seq 1828956934, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:10:23.316571 IP 212.73.221.202.80 > 192.168.1.2.64834: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1828956935, win 0, length 0
21:10:23.816987 IP 192.168.1.2.64834 > 212.73.221.202.80: Flags [S], seq 1828956934, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:10:23.817020 IP 212.73.221.202.80 > 192.168.1.2.64834: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
21:10:24.317986 IP 192.168.1.2.64834 > 212.73.221.202.80: Flags [S], seq 1828956934, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:10:24.318001 IP 212.73.221.202.80 > 192.168.1.2.64834: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
21:10:24.323263 IP 192.168.1.2.64836 > 38.124.168.119.80: Flags [S], seq 695092282, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:10:24.323277 IP 38.124.168.119.80 > 192.168.1.2.64836: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 695092283, win 0, length 0
21:10:24.831593 IP 192.168.1.2.64836 > 38.124.168.119.80: Flags [S], seq 695092282, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:10:24.831623 IP 38.124.168.119.80 > 192.168.1.2.64836: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
```

as you can see the server responses to the client but still unable to connect to the internet.

any help ?

Comment: Why do you SNAT to 192.168.1.3 ? Going to internet i think you should SNAT to public IP ?

Comment: The network design is somehow confusing, the `client`, `clients gateway` and `localnet gateway` servers are all on the same network, so when a client sends a request through `clients gateway` it resend the request to `localnet gateway`, and when the target server responses the response is sent directly from `localnet gateway` to `client` instead of `clients gateway` then `client`, that cause breaking tcp connection. Never mind, I don't think the problem in SNATing.

Comment: From Client, what says `traceroute google.com` (or `tracert google.com`) ?

Comment: It traceroutes successfully as the icmp protocol won't be tunneled through sshuttle, when stopping sshuttle the internet works fine on clients but I want to tunnel the requests.

Comment: I would tunnel ICMP, it will be easier to debug...

Comment: @krisFR I don't think I can tunnel ICMP trough ssh